# Unable to retrieve image from Parse (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've been working on this problem for almost two days now and still can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to load a saved image from Parse onto a UIImageView. I have another function that does this for two pieces of text but when I try retrieving the image, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
  func showImage() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Description")
    query.orderByDescending("ceatedAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.images = [UIImage]()
        if let objects = objects {
            for imageObject in objects {

                let userImage = (imageObject as! PFObject)["UserPhoto"] as? PFFile
                if userImage != nil {
                    userImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData, error) -> Void in


                        if error == nil {
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                            self.images.append(image!)

                        }
                        self.theTableView.reloadData()
                    }}

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the `error == nil` and data is retrieved? log error and check. Otherwise try reloading tableview in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

please try after change this line of code query.orderByDescending("ceatedAt") to query.orderByDescending("createdAt").

Comment: I caught that and still didn't work. If I comment out this function to retrieve the image, my retrieved text fields will show but if I keep this function then nothing shows...the text fields go away. Any idea why?

Comment: No, no error. The image and text still save to Parse but just doesn't display.